# QGIS plugins deployment

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I've been upload my own qgis plugin into this:
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Otoklim/

But the plugins has no public version yet..

I didn't get any message from QGIS and i don't know where to ask..

Is there any steps that i should do before uploading to QGIS repository so the plugins can be public version and able to be downloaded via QGIS plugins menu..?

Comment: Did you follow some of the guidance mentioned in the following link?: [Releasing your plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/releasing.html).

Comment: It can take several days before your plugin being approved by a community member.

Comment: I am in the same situation. 5 days have passed and no reaction. My plugin yet not public. How did you solve this question?